# MySQL search with word distance across neighboring records

Tags: php, mysql, distance, levenshtein-distance

I am performing a keyword text search across static records in a MySQL database.  Is it possible to construct a query that finds the first keyword in a record and the second keyword in a neighboring record?  Consider the following sample data.

```
------------------------------------------------------
| id | textstrings                                   |
------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | Every good boy does fine.                     |
|  2 | The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. |
|  3 | I will not eat green eggs and ham.            |
|  4 | There is no time like the present.            |
|  5 | Envy is an ugly shade of green.               |
------------------------------------------------------
```

A search for the terms `green brown` should return records 2 and 3 since they are neighboring records, but should not contain record 5 since it is not a neighbor with record 3.

I know that I can perform a query for either of the words and accomplish this by processing the result set, but I would like to know if it's possible to build this into the query.

This field does have a FULLTEXT index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join together two queries, one which will search for ids containing the first search string (`green` in this example), and the other which will search for ids containing the second search string (`brown` here).

The `SELECT` statement is structured the way it is to remove duplicate adjacent `id` pairs which may occur as a result of the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT LEAST(t1.id, t2.id) AS id1, GREATEST(t1.id, t2.id) AS id2
FROM
(
    SELECT id
    FROM table
    WHERE textstrings LIKE '%green%'
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM table
    WHERE textstrings LIKE '%brown%'
) t2
ON t1.id = t2.id - 1 OR t1.id = t2.id + 1
GROUP BY LEAST(t1.id, t2.id), GREATEST(t1.id, t2.id)
```

Click the link below for a running demo.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c194c1/6)

Comment: That is very elegant!  Is it possible to add a distance?  As in, within 2 records apart.  I don't need it, now I'm just curious.

Comment: If you want records 2 apart (and only 2 apart), you can change the `WHERE` clause to: `t1.id = t2.id - 2 OR t1.id = t2.id + 2`

Comment: I think I have my head wrapped around it now.  Very nice.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: For anyone else interested, you can limit up to a certain distance by adjusting the comparisons.  For records that are no more than 3 apart, inclusively, you can use `ON t1.id >= t2.id - 3 AND t1.id <= t2.id + 3`.  Adjust the number `3` for the distance between records as needed.